# Xslt Error: 'tr' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:text' element

Tags: xslt

Please explain to me how to include a plain html inside an XSL template

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() = last()">
<xsl:text><tr><td colspan='10'>bla bla.</td></tr></xsl:text></xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Error: 'tr' cannot be a child of the 'xsl:text' element.

Thanks !

Comment: Asking such question indicates the asker is at ground zero with the subject of XSLT. Read a good book on the subject -- this will save you time and confusion asking a lot of minor and unrelated questions whose answers won't help understand the basics and fundamental principles of the language.

Comment: To make an absolute statement such as "nobody reads books anymore" is a factual error. *If* there are such people, this is their personal and social problem.

Comment: I have no interest in XSL, just need to fix a thing inherited from a former coworker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the `<xsl:text>` tags:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="position() = last()">
  <tr><td colspan="10">bla bla.</td></tr>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

An `<xsl:text>` element means "insert text here". Therefore, its content must only consist of text nodes. You can, however, simply write out the text; the following two lines are equivalent:

```
<xsl:text>foo bar</xsl:text>
foo bar
```